# How did this tag not get burninated on its [date-of-birth]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [date-of-birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-of-birth) says

> For questions related to storing, retrieving, and viewing Date of Birth (DoB) information.

Again, the burnination questions:

*Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

Well, it could mean storing the date of birth using a program. It could also mean that the OP is looking for a blank calendar to note the date of birth on.

*Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

A programming language doesn't care if a question is about a date of birth or any other arbitrary date. So no, it does not describe the contents.

It's definitely ambiguous. The tag wiki says it could mean

- storing
- retrieving, or
- viewing.

*Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

As I said, "date of birth" isn't different from any other date. At least to the compiler.

*Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?*

Finding a calendar is obviously off-topic. Support for calendar programs is also off-topic.

There are 94 questions with the tag.  It is never the only tag on the question.  Many different language tags are used with it.

Can we please, please burn this tag?

Comment: It *is* different from other dates when it comes to GDPR...

Comment: But isn't that a legal problem rather than something pertaining to programming?  In the context of filesystems that support the feature it is also something different from what someone using an app to store a person's date of birth in a database thinks of...

Comment: @Glorfindel Questions focusing on that topic would be off-topic as we don't do legal, licensing etc here.

Comment: I think that particially cements why it's not relevant here though, @BaummitAugen . From a literal data perspective a Date of Birth is a date like any other. From a GDPR perspective it's personal data, however, the fact doesn't matter on [main] as it falls under law. Either the question is generically about dates, so a tag like [[tag:date]] should be used, or it's it's about the PII side of dates of birth which shouldn't be asked here as it's off topic.

Comment: After a quick look at the some of the 100 questions tagged [tag:date-of-birth], it seems that many of them are simply general date type questions that just happen to be be using a birthday (often using differences in dates). The [tag:date] tag should suffice for these. Some others are related getting the "date of birth" value using a particular API.

Comment: The fact that the date happens to be the DoB is irrelevant to programming.

Comment: Android, for example, will use a date specifically typed birthday in their contacts data. While it may be a date, that doesn't mean it behaves similarly or that people treat it the same as a normal date in all contexts. Regardless of privacy, or legal, programmers are having to customize their implementations in order to handle specific scenarios with birthdays as opposed to an arbitrary day.

Comment: There may be legitimate programming questions about how to securely manage PII (e.g., using specific tools or protocols), but in that context it never matters that the PII in question is a date.

Comment: I think the argument that it needs to be a synonym is a valid one. I have added a synonym and will merge later

Comment: We should also burn [tag:dob] if we burn this tag.

Comment: @Machavity Could you please do the same thing with [tag:dob] as mentioned in the comment above this one? It's excerpt is "DOB is a common abbreviation of Date of Birth".

Comment: @CrisLuengo Done

Comment: There is one very marginal context in which it could be worthwhile, and not just any date. That's in the HTML 5 context of the autocomplete attribute, "bday"
A birth date, as a full date.

"bday-day"
The day of the month of a birth date.

"bday-month"
The month of the year of a birth date.

"bday-year"
The year of a birth date.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

I would still vote to burn it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think the tag should be merged into [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date). Not all the [date-of-birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-of-birth) questions are even tagged with it, so it would help to bring all the information to one place. On many of these questions, [date-arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-arithmetic) would also be appropriate. To quote the question:

> "date of birth" isn't different from any other date

There are only a few questions that are about a DoB but not a date, such as:

- [How to get birthday of Google account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65119515/6083675)
- [Meetup API, how to get gender and birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483321/6083675)

These questions may not need a tag for that at all. (It seems silly to have a tag for every field of information, or even the most common, that can be gotten with any API.)